# Python - How to open Windows share using user name and password

Tags: python, windows

I would like to access Windows share (ex. \backupserver\backups) from Python script. Share is protected by user name and password. How to open this share using user name and password and, for example list its content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you mount the related share using the

```
NET USE
```

command?

Calling `NET USE` from through the subprocess module is straight forward.

Comment: Answer provides little insight into why and how the solution works.

Answer (score 12):

Complete example for "NET USE":

```
backup_storage_available = os.path.isdir(BACKUP_REPOSITORY_PATH)

if backup_storage_available:
    logger.info("Backup storage already connected.")
else:
    logger.info("Connecting to backup storage.")

    mount_command = "net use /user:" + BACKUP_REPOSITORY_USER_NAME + " " + BACKUP_REPOSITORY_PATH + " " + BACKUP_REPOSITORY_USER_PASSWORD
    os.system(mount_command)
    backup_storage_available = os.path.isdir(BACKUP_REPOSITORY_PATH)

    if backup_storage_available:
        logger.fine("Connection success.")
    else:
        raise Exception("Failed to find storage directory.")
```

Answer (score 9):

Using [`pywin32`](http://pywin32.sourceforge.net/) (Python for Windows Extensions),
access the windows networking methods in the `win32wnet` module.
The [`win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2()`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32wnet__WNetAddConnection2_meth.html) method lets you specify username and password.

```
WNetAddConnection2(NetResource, Password, UserName, Flags)
```

> Creates a connection to a network resource. The function can redirect a local device to the network resource.

After the connection is active, access the share using regular directory and file methods.

Comment: An example of NetResource definition: `NetResource = win32wnet.NETRESOURCE()` `NetResource.lpRemoteName = r'\\10.0.0.1\share'`

Answer (score 1):

A nice library that wraps 'net use' command:

http://covenanteyes.github.io/py_win_unc/