# How to open protected Windows share using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, windows-share

How do I open Windows share with credentials using Python on a Windows machine?

I'm currently doing this:

```
share = open(r'share@username:password','r')
```

Comment: check this out for some info. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593198/python-how-to-open-windows-share-using-user-name-and-password)

Comment: thanks @SheaBelsky

Answer (score 0):

i used

subprocess.call(r'net use z: \windows_server\share /user:@username password', shell=True)
to mount the share and

subprocess.call(r'net use z: /delete')

to delete it.This is the most hassle free and efficient way. Thanks everyone for the help!!